# How to set window to active window based on QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, window, focus, qt5

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTime>
#include <QProcess>

bool started = false;
QString path;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Waiting for input...");
    QFile file("path.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", file.errorString());
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    path = in.readLine();
    file.close();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    qApp->exit();
}

void delay(int n)
{
    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(n);
    while(QTime::currentTime() < dieTime)
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(!started) {
        started = true;

        qint32 waitSecs = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText().toInt();
        QTime launchTime = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(waitSecs);

        while(waitSecs > 0) {
            waitSecs = QTime::currentTime().secsTo(launchTime);
            ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString("Waiting %1 seconds to launch BLR launcher.").arg(waitSecs));
            delay(1);
        }

        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Launching BLR launcher!");

        QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
        process->start(path, QStringList() << "");
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above (read the last few lines), I have a process that is started. I want to make sure that the window that starts (by that process) is focused.

I know there is this function: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setActiveWindow

It requires a QWidget as a parameter. Maybe I need to convert QProcess to Qwidget?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just calling the executable directly in the call to QProcess::start, use it as a parameter to a relevant open command in your operating system.

For example, in OSX I'd use

```
process->start("open programToRun.app");
```

If you're in Windows, I'm sure there's an equivalent, perhaps using:

```
process->start("cmd programToRun.exe").
```

Hoep that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I thought you wanted the app launched from Process to be given focus when launched?